# how to get color at the spot(or pixel) of a image on touch event in android

Tags: android, image, colors, imageview, pixel

I want to get the color of the spot or pixel where I will touch a image in Android. I searched a lot on net, but got nothing. Please anyone help me.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

try this:

```
final Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
        int x = (int)event.getX();
        int y = (int)event.getY();
        int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);

        //then do what you want with the pixel data, e.g
        int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
        int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
        int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);        
        return false;
        }
   });
```

Comment: Beware that image can be scaled. Solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496339/android-imageview-get-pixel-color-from-scaled-image

Answer (score 3):

You can compute the image coordinates of the pixel that was clicked and read the pixel from the image data, like

```
Bitmap.getPixel(xcord,ycord)
```

Comment: I need to get the pixel when i have scaled my image. I tried every solution but get only white color in return