# How to get the RGB values from am imageview in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

**What i am trying to do:** I am trying to get the RGB values from an image

---

**What is happening:** I am getting the null pointer exception in

```
final Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imgUsrClrId.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

---

**Question:** This is happening in `fragments` as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14920800/1083093) it is working for activity, i guess i am not able to get the `imageview` properly for `fragments`. ***HOW CAN I RESOLVE THIS !!***

---

**MyClass.java**

```
public class MyClass extends Fragment {


    //View object variables
    TextView tvAllSymptomsId,tvGenderId,txtColorCodeId;
    Button btnRotateId;
    ImageView imgUsrClrId;


    public MyClass() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.symptom_checker, container,false);

        //Find the views
        tvAllSymptomsId=(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvAllSymptomsId);
        tvGenderId=(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvGenderId);
        btnRotateId=(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnRotateId);
        imgUsrClrId=(ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgUsrClrId);
        txtColorCodeId=(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtColorCodeId);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        //Initially set the image as female facing front
        imgUsrClrId.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.female_front));

        final Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imgUsrClrId.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        imgUsrClrId.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
            int x = (int)event.getX();
            int y = (int)event.getY();
            int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);

            //then do what you want with the pixel data, e.g
            int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
            int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
            int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);  

            txtColorCodeId.setText(redValue+greenValue+blueValue);
            return false;
            }
       });
    }
}
```

**XML code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgUsrClrId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/female_front"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGenderId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imgUsrClrId"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgUsrClrId"
        android:text="Gender" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAllSymptomsId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imgUsrClrId"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:text="All Symptoms" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRotateId"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgUsrClrId"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvAllSymptomsId"
        android:background="@drawable/rotate" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtColorCodeId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are writing code in wrong place you will get ImageView object in onActivityCreated method instead of onStart()

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    /* Write code to get reference of ImageView and Get value of Bitmap RGB here */

}
```

Update :

that means ImageView Instance is not null but the drawable is

you are setting Background drawable and you need to access it like below

```
Drawable background = view.getBackground();
if (background instanceof BitmapDrawable)
{
   Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)background).getBitmap();
}
```

Comment: Even if i move code here i get similar result(null pointer error)

Comment: see edit above you are trying to access background drawable in incorrect way.

Answer (score 1):

Move this code to `onCreateView()` method.

```
imgUsrClrId.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.female_front));

    final Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imgUsrClrId.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    imgUsrClrId.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
        int x = (int)event.getX();
        int y = (int)event.getY();
        int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);

        //then do what you want with the pixel data, e.g
        int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
        int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
        int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);  

        txtColorCodeId.setText(redValue+greenValue+blueValue);
        return false;
        }
   });
```

Initially your `imgUsrClrId` is null. In `onStart()` method `Fragment` will be visible so it gets value of `imgUsrClrId` null at first.

Comment: @ Piyush Gupta .... Still there is nullPointer error .... `final Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imgUsrClrId.getDrawable()).getBitmap();`  is still  giving this error

Comment: Please show your symptom_checker.xml file. And yes have you added code before return your rootView?

Comment: Is it symptom_checker.xml files sure?

Comment: Yes because i have only one xml ..... this issue is regarding getting image from image view in fragments i guess !

Comment: Also try to use this  `imgUsrClrId.setBackgroundDrawable(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.female_front));` Or use `imgUsrClrId.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.female_front)`;Because `setBackgroundDrawable()` method is deprecated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64285/discussion-between-devrath-and-piyush-gupta).