# How to get color values from certain spots(Coordinates) of an image in android?

Tags: java, android, image, canvas

I am writing an android app but am new to this.

I want to upload an image from storage and find the color values of certain spots in the image, not on click but automatically
and store them in a list or array.

I repeat I am new to this, I know there is a onTouch event which gets coordinates of where you touch the image.

I do not know how to get coordinates of a certain spot automatically without any interaction on the image by user. I want to press a button and it goes and gets certain coordinates colors.

Please help me out instead of referring me to the Ontouch version page

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get color at the spot(or pixel) of a image on touch event in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920303/how-to-get-color-at-the-spotor-pixel-of-a-image-on-touch-event-in-android)

Comment: I agree that this is duplicate. I know that the other questions is handling it in a click event, but it still shows how you can use the coordinates to get the color.

Comment: As I mentioned I am very new to android, I understand the on touch code 
however do not know how to only get color values of certain coordinates without any touch.